# Hibernate lazy loading not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm using version 3.6.1.Final

I have the following property in my entity bean

```
    @JoinColumn( name = "FOLDER_PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "FOLDER_ID" )
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, fetch= FetchType.LAZY )
private FolderTbl parent;
```

In my unit test, Assertnull fails because getParent() is not null

```
assertNull( folderTbl.getParent() );
```

What else do I have to do to stop hibernate loading the parent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even if you set the lazy to true, the parent value will not be null. The lazy load uses a proxy object and assign it to the parent property. When we try to use the parent(call `getParent()`) it will load the actual parent object using the proxy object.

If you do not want to load the object do not configure the JPA properties for the item and set it as transient.

Comment: Also check your logs for things like "Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [xxxxx] for the entity class [class xxx.xxx.xx] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.

Answer (score 10):

Parent is configured **correctly** to *load lazily* , the point is you are **testing it wrongly**.

Hibernate will load the object when you invoke the method `getParent()` , when request to actual object comes it will load .

You can check this thing by configuring `show_sql` to true. it will invoke a query when you invoke  `getParent()`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, invoking getParent() might return a proxy instance that shows you there is a parent.
If you access fields other than the id the parent would be loaded if necessary.

Note that the parent might be loaded already by the transaction and thus reside in the first level cache. If so, Hibernate normally won't do another query to the database.

As said before, if your entity has a non-transient reference to a parent getParent() will always return a non-null value, even if the parent itself is not loaded yet.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate treats the Lazy fetching as a hint. Here is what the JPA 2.0 spec says on page 364 Table 9.

> (Optional) Whether the value of the field or property
>   should be lazily loaded or must be eagerly fetched. The
>   EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider
>   runtime that the value must be eagerly fetched. The
>   LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime.

Answer (score 0):

For some scenarios you might need not load the lazy collection at all. You can have a method like below to detach the collection from the session.

```
public class. .... {
.....
  @JoinColumn( name = "FOLDER_PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "FOLDER_ID" )
  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, fetch= FetchType.LAZY )
  private FolderTbl parent;
  ...
  public void detachLazyObjects() {
     parent = null;
  }
```

Then call this method to detach the class from where you need it to be null. Please use this shortcut sparingly, I would suggest you to think about other ways of doing it before resorting to this solution.